Criteria for weak convergence implies norm convergence on Banach spaces
Let $(E, \| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space and $E':=\{ \phi : E \to \mathbb K \| \phi  \text{ is $\mathbb K$-linear}, \phi \text{ is continuous} \}$ denote the dual space $(\mathbb K \in \{ \mathbb R, \mathbb C \})$. A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subseteq E$ is $\mathbf{weak \ convergent}$ if and only if $\exists x\in E \forall \phi \in E': \lim_{n\to \infty} \phi(x_n)=\phi(x)$. Its easy to see that norm  convergence implies weak convergence, but the opposite is wrong in general (a counterexample is given down below).
But there definetly are Banach spaces, where both definitions are equivalent. For example, on finite dimensional spaces. But this again is no equivalence, because there are definitely infinite dimensional spaces where both types of convergence are equivalent, for example the famous space complex valued (countable) summable sequences $\ell^1(\mathbb N; \mathbb C)$. So a 'smooth' solution like 'norm convergence $=$ weak convergence if and only if finite dimension' cant be true again.
This is what makes be being very curious about criterias for 'weak convergence implies norm convergence' (if they even exist), because something is definetly going on here.
My first thought was that if the coordinate projections (take a non-zero $x\in E$, choose a basis that contains $x_0:= x \in {x_n}_{n\in I}$, than the coordinate projection of $x$ is the map $\sum \lambda_nx_n \mapsto \lambda_0$ ), or the coordinate projections of a fixed hamel (or schauder) basis, are continuous, that might suffice for weak and norm convergence to be equivalent. But i was proven wrong by the trivial fact that $(e_n)_{ n \in \mathbb N} \subseteq \ell^2(\mathbb N; \mathbb C)$ ( $e_n$ is the sequence that is everywhere $0$ except at the n-th position, here it is $1$) is weakly convergent to $0$ but the norm is constantly one. This is a counterexample because of the orthogonality the coordinate projections (of a fixed ONB) are continuous on Hilbert spaces (like for example $\ell^2(\mathbb N; \mathbb C))$.
To be honest I dont know how and where to continue and would definetly be glad to hear any ideas or solutions on this topic, i.e.: Does anyone know an criteria, the norm/space must fulfill, for norm and weak convergent to be equivalent?
Thanks a lot!

The property that any weakly convergent sequence also converges in norm is called Schur’s property. I don’t believe there’s any easy-to-state sufficient condition for it, though. Nor do I believe there’s any well-known infinite-dimensional example apart from $\ell^1$. Note that I emphasized sequence in the above. If you require any weakly convergent net to also converge in norm, then the only possibility is a finite-dimensional space.

(Also, the coordinate projections w.r.t. a Schauder basis are always all continuous. And the coordinate projections w.r.t. a Hamel basis are never all continuous unless the space is finite-dimensional - in fact, given a Hamel basis, there are always at most finitely many coordinate projections w.r.t. this basis that are continuous. So those criteria are completely irrelevant.)

You have to specify an entire Hamel basis before being able to talk about coordinate projections, and then the coordinate projections w.r.t. the Hamel basis don’t really have much to do with the orthogonal coordinate projections w.r.t. the ONB anymore. As an example, say ${e_n}$ is an ONB. Then $v = \sum_n \frac{1}{n}e_n$ is linearly independent from ${e_n}$, so there is a Hamel basis containing ${e_n}$ and $v$. Then $v$, written in terms of this Hamel basis, is just itself, so its projection w.r.t. any $e_n$ is zero, but the orthogonal coordinate projections give $\frac{1}{n}$ instead.

In (locally) uniformly convex Banach spaces, weak convergence + convergence of the norms ($|x_n|\to |x|)$ imply norm convergence. Such Banach spaces include Hilbert spaces and the "classic" function spaces $L^p, W^{1,p}$ for $1<p<\infty$

Another relation is that weak convergence is equivalent to norm convergence on subsets which are compact in the norm topology.

@DeanMiller do you have any reference for this?

@TimonKolt I don't know a reference but the proof is straightforward. Let $K$ be a subset of a normed space $X$ which is compact in the norm topology. The identity map $i:(K,|\cdot|) \to (K, w)$ is a continuous bijection. Since the weak topology is Hausdorff, $i$ maps closed sets to closed sets and is consequently a homeomorphism.

Collecting the helpful comments to a complete answer.
The property that weak convergence implies norm convergence is called Schur Property. But (aside from the finite dimensional case) the only well known example is $\ell^1$. Other $\ell^p$ spaces $(p< \infty)$ fail to have this property since $e_n \to 0$ weakly, but $\|e_n \|_p = 1$. In fact this condition is strongly connected to $\ell^1$ since for example: For any banach space $X$ with the schur property every closed, infinite dimensional subspace has an to $\ell^1$ isomorphic subspace. This wikipedia article provides some interesting conditions of such spaces (such like non-reflexivity, quotient spaces fail to inherit this property etc.), unfortunately its written in german, so a non german speaker might need some translation tools.
Also: Given a Schauder or orthonormal Basis, the  coordinate projections are always all continuous, while for infinite dimensional banach spaces the coordinate projections are never all continuous. In fact: a maximum of finitely many of those are continuous. So this criteria is absolutely irrelevant. To see this note that you have to fix an entire hamel basis, before beeing able to talk about such coordinate projections.
These two parts were strongly influenced by the comments from @DavidGao.
In uniformly convex banach spaces, for example pre-hilbert spaces, $L^p$-spaces $(1 < p < \infty)$, have a similar property:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n-x\| \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| = \|x\| \wedge  x_n \to x\text{ weakly}$$
So there is a "smooth" additional property that makes underlying weak convergence to norm convergence.
This was mentioned by @EvangelopoulosFoivos in the comments above.
Another relation is that weak convergence is equivalent to norm convergence on compact subsets. To see this, let $K$ be a compact subset, $\omega$ the weak topology, then the identity map $i:(K, \| \cdot \|) \to (K, \omega)$ is clearly continuous (and a bijection). This means that $i$ maps closed sets (they are compact since $K$ is compact) on compact sets, which are closed since $\omega$ is hausdorff. This makes $i$ an homeomorphism and gives the required equivalence of norm convergence and weak convergence.
This information was given by @DeanMiller in the comments above.
